# Only five solvable quintic equations of the form $x^5+ax^2+b=0$? What are their solutions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots, irreducible-polynomials

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Other_solvable_quintics) there are only five solvable quintic equations of the form $x^5+ax^2+b=0,~~a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ (up to a scaling constant $s$).

$$x^5-2s^3x^2-\frac{s^5}{5}=0 $$
$$ x^5-100s^3x^2-1000s^5=0 $$
$$x^5-5s^3x^2-3s^5=0  $$
$$x^5-5s^3x^2+15s^5=0  $$
$$ x^5-25s^3x^2-300s^5=0 $$

But the source of this claim is a [web-page](https://web.archive.org/web/20171118223859/http://www.math.harvard.edu/%7Eelkies/trinomial.html) (even if it's Harvard), not an article.

Thus, my questions are:

> Why is this true, and what is the original source of this knowledge?
>
> What are the solutions to these equations (in radical form, or possibly trigonometric/hyperbolic form)?

**Edit**

I found the proper citation on the linked Web-Page (for which I sincerely thank the author, if they ever visit this post).

The paper is [On Solvable Quintics $X^5+aX+b$ and $X^5+aX^2+b$](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmjm/1181072083) by Blair K. Spearman and Kenneth S. Williams and the full text is available with open-access. I will see if my questions are answered by this paper and update the post.

Comment: [This](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html) is an occasionally used visualization of solvable quintics. I don't know how to transform those equations into the form used in your source.

Comment: Some of these quintics can be expressed by trigonometric functions with arguments involving the _golden ratio_. See second answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the linked paper [On Solvable Quintics $X^5+aX+b$ and $X^5+aX^2+b$](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmjm/1181072083) by Blair K. Spearman and Kenneth S. Williams, the solutions are as follows (we take $s=5$ in the first equation and $s=1$ for the rest):

> $$x=\omega^{j}u_1+\omega^{2j}u_2+\omega^{3j}u_3+\omega^{4j}u_4$$

$\omega$ - the fifth root of unity.

> $$x^5-5x^2-3=0  $$

$$u_1=\left(-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{20}-\frac{1}{100} \sqrt{150+30\sqrt{5}}+\frac{1}{50} \sqrt{150-30\sqrt{5}} \right)^{1/5}$$

$$u_2=\left(-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{20}-\frac{1}{100} \sqrt{150+30\sqrt{5}}-\frac{1}{50} \sqrt{150-30\sqrt{5}}\right)^{1/5}$$

$$u_3=\left(-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{20}+\frac{1}{100} \sqrt{150+30\sqrt{5}}+\frac{1}{50} \sqrt{150-30\sqrt{5}}\right)^{1/5}$$

$$u_4=\left(-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{20}+\frac{1}{100} \sqrt{150+30\sqrt{5}}-\frac{1}{50} \sqrt{150-30\sqrt{5}}\right)^{1/5}$$

---

> $$x^5-5x^2+15=0  $$

$$u_1=\left(\frac{5}{4} + \frac{13\sqrt{5}}{20} - \frac{7}{100} \sqrt{750+330\sqrt{5}} \right)^{1/5}$$

$$u_2=\left(\frac{5}{4} - \frac{13\sqrt{5}}{20} - \frac{7}{100} \sqrt{750-330\sqrt{5}} \right)^{1/5}$$

$$u_3=\left(\frac{5}{4} - \frac{13\sqrt{5}}{20} + \frac{7}{100} \sqrt{750-330\sqrt{5}} \right)^{1/5}$$

$$u_4=\left(\frac{5}{4} + \frac{13\sqrt{5}}{20} + \frac{7}{100} \sqrt{750+330\sqrt{5}} \right)^{1/5}$$

---

> $$ x^5-25x^2-300=0 $$

$$u_1=\left(-\frac{25}{2} - \frac{5\sqrt{5}}{2} - \frac{5}{2} \sqrt{30+6\sqrt{5}} \right)^{1/5}$$

$$u_2=\left(-\frac{25}{2} + \frac{5\sqrt{5}}{2} - \frac{5}{2} \sqrt{30-6\sqrt{5}} \right)^{1/5}$$

$$u_3=\left(-\frac{25}{2} + \frac{5\sqrt{5}}{2} + \frac{5}{2} \sqrt{30-6\sqrt{5}} \right)^{1/5}$$

$$u_4=\left(-\frac{25}{2} - \frac{5\sqrt{5}}{2} + \frac{5}{2} \sqrt{30+6\sqrt{5}} \right)^{1/5}$$

---

> $$ x^5-100x^2-1000=0 $$

$$u_1=-2^{6/5},~~~~u_2=-2^{7/5},~~~~u_3=2^{3/5},~~~~u_4=-2^{4/5}$$

---

> $$x^5-250x^2-625=0 $$

$$u_1=(-125+50 \sqrt{5})^{1/5}$$

$$u_2=\frac{(-375-175 \sqrt{5})^{1/5}}{2^{1/5}}$$

$$u_3=\frac{(-375+175 \sqrt{5})^{1/5}}{2^{1/5}}$$

$$u_4=(-125-50 \sqrt{5})^{1/5}$$

Comment: How should I proceed in order to get the roots of the polynomial? Substitute j as 0,1,2,3,4 and the respective $u's$ but what root of unity $w$ should be?

Comment: @Mr.N, I'm not sure. I think it would be better if you look up the linked paper, maybe it contains more information

Answer (score 2):

Like all solvable quintics, these can be expressed in terms of *trigonometric* and *inverse trigonometric* functions, and two of them have nice representations using the ***golden ratio***,

$$\phi = \tfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

The unique real roots are given by,

> **I.** $\quad x^5-5x^2-3=0  $

$$x=\frac{-2}{5^{1/4}}\left(\cos\Big(\tfrac{1}{5}\arccos\big(\frac{5^{3/4}}{2\,\phi}\big)\Big)-i\,\sin\Big(\tfrac{1}{5}\arcsin\big(\frac{5^{3/4}\phi\;i}{2}\big)\Big)\right)=-1.8087\dots$$

> **III.** $\quad  x^5-25x^2-300=0 $

$$x=2\cdot 5^{1/4}\left(\cos\Big(\tfrac{1}{5}\arccos\big(5^{1/4}\phi\big)\Big)-i\,\sin\Big(\tfrac{1}{5}\arcsin\big(\frac{5^{1/4}\;i}{\phi}\big)\Big)\right)=3.6287\dots $$

Comment: Not all solvable quintic can be expressed with trigonometric functions and their inverses.  Only if the roots are all real is such a representation obtained.  If instead there is only _one_ real riot it would be expressed with hyperbolic functions and their inverses instead, or directly with radicals.

Comment: @OscarLanzi I just noticed this comment now. Actually even if a solvable quintic has one real root, you can bypass hypergeometric functions and express the quintic as a sum of **TWO** trigonometric functions (and their inverses) as shown by the examples above (which are one-real root quintics.) I'll try to give a more general formula later.

Comment: Those examples are not conveniently rendered in terms of  trig functions. To get answers in real variables you have to use hyperbolic functions because the arguments of the inverse hyperbolic cosines are greater than $1$ and the arguments of the inverse sines are imaginary. Using the hyperbolic/exponential relations the hyperbolic function combinations can then be converted to algebraic radicals.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Since we have the identity, 
$$\sinh\big(\tfrac15\operatorname{arcsinh}(x)\big)=-i \sin\big(\tfrac15\arcsin(x \sqrt{-1})\big)$$
thus one side is **equally** valid as the other. You prefer the LHS, but I used the RHS instead. To discuss which side of an *equality* is "convenient" or "better" is a matter of taste, and frankly a waste of time.